# RuntimeError: shape '[-1, 1433, 16]' is invalid for input of size 64

Tags: python

I want to use NNConv in pytorch on Cora dataset, the following code is my model and train function:

```py
edge_attr = 10
input_features = torch.rand(1,edge_attr)

class NNConv(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim):
        super(NNConv, self).__init__()
        nn1 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(edge_attr, 64), nn.ReLU())
        nn2 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(edge_attr, 64), nn.ReLU())

        self.conv1 = NNConv(input_dim, hidden_dim, nn=nn1, aggr='mean')
        self.conv2 = NNConv(hidden_dim, output_dim, nn=nn2, aggr='mean')

    def forward(self, x, edge_index):
        x = self.conv1(x, edge_index, input_features)
        x = torch.relu(x)
        x = self.conv2(x, edge_index, input_features)
        return x

model = NNConv(dataset.num_features, 16, dataset.num_classes)

def train(model, data, epochs, lr):
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

    model.train()
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(data.x, data.edge_index)
        loss = criterion(output[data.train_mask], data.y[data.train_mask])
        loss.backward()
        Losses.append(loss.detach().item())
        optimizer.step()

        if epoch % 10 == 0:
            acc = evaluate(model, data)
            print(f'Epoch: {epoch}, Loss: {loss.item()}')


train(model, data, epochs=200, lr=0.01)
```

`data.x` is the feature matrix for nodes, `data.edge_index` is the a matrix with size of 2*10556 for edge index and `edge_attr` is random matrix (because there is no features for edges in cora dataset).

but I have this error:

```
RuntimeError: shape '[-1, 1433, 16]' is invalid for input of size 64
```

I want to implement NNConv method in pytorch on core dataset.